# Adding array elements Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, sum

Why this code returns 10 instead of 2?

```
var arrToSum = [2, 4, 10];
function sumArray(array) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = array[0]; i < array.length; i++) {
    result += array[i];
    }
  return result;
}
sumArray(arrToSum);

// function returns 10
```

If following loop logic, I would end after adding ***2*** to ***result*** variable, because next ***i*** is equal to 3 and loop should end. Please explain what happens there.

Comment: Because `i` runs from `2` to `2`, effectively only adding `arr[2]` (`10`) to `0`. It's not clear to me what you are intending with `var i = array[0];`. To expand a bit: *"because next `i` is equal to `3`"* Yes, you are adding only a single value, the loop stops after a single iteration, but since `i` starts at `2` you are adding `arr[2]`, not `arr[0]`. Btw, if you want to understand what exactly your code is doing, set a breakpoint, step through your code step by step and inspect the variables.

Comment: Because `array[2]` is 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How things are working in for loop:**

`for (var i = array[0]; i < array.length; i++) {`

In the loop, these are the results after execution of first Iteration;

**First Iteration; i = 2**

```
var i = array[0]; // i = 2;
result += array[i]; // result = 10;
```

`array[i]` is `array[2]` which is 10. Hence, the `result` is 10.

**Second Iteration; i = 3**

`array.length` is 3 since it has 3 elements. Condition  `i < array.length;` is false and code Breaks out of loop, returning the Result as 10.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting from 2 (value of array[0]), not from 0. Change

```
for (var i = array[0]; i < array.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should familiarize yourself with functional programming in javascript. `map`, `filter`, `reduce` are your friends. Especially `map`.

Try to avoid regular loops as much as possible cause they are more error prone. In your case you've messed up with counter variable `i`.

```
var sum = [2, 4, 10].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```